Noticing different behavior of randomness for texture-based displacement in EEVEE and Cycles Rendered Preview
I have an object, and I created three instances for it using Geometry Nodes. I wanted different displacement for each instance, based on noise texture for each instance (to make surface uneven/distort).
To do so, I stored a named attribute in Geo Nodes and used it in material nodes to create random noise and eventually random displacement:

The thing is, it works as expected in Rendered Preview when I use EEVEE. Each instance is a great deal random in terms of uneven surface:

But if I switch to Cycles, it appears the boundaries of each instance is exactly same, the distortion also looks exactly same, so overall shape of each instance is apparently same:

The behavior was same when I tried with other objects like cube or sphere.
Interestingly, in a separate test file, I tried to use that attribute for random color for each instance's surface, and it worked without any issues. With both Cycles and EEVEE.
So I want to know why there's this different behavior? Am I doing something wrong, or do I need to do more adjustment/changes to make it work with Cycles too?

I've uploaded blender file on Google Drive if needed. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JXxWecjc4CdSzJIaFIghvLBnYdIxn4we/view?usp=sharing

I'm taking a wild guess here, but it may be a limitation of instancing on GPU, where each instance just has to share the geometry and there's no way in the pipeline to displace instances separately, meanwhile perhaps Eevee does this on the CPU

This appears to be a bug/mismatch in logic between the two renderers.
However, if you want your effect to work in cycles you just need to realize instances. This will work in both EEVEE and Cycles.
Realize instances





EEVEE
CYCLES









